# Python ERROR : library matplotlib.pyplot to run LIVE GRAPH

Tags: python

I can't run my code using python3.10.1, matplotlib 3.8.2 istalled.
Now i'm using in vscode the python terminal to run a live graph with matplotlib.
The main problem is created by the incompatibility to analize the latest row like : .clear() ,  .plot()  , set_title ()  , .setylim().

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1)
fig.suptitle('Temperature and Humidity Live Data')

x = np.linspace(0, 100, 100)
y1 = np.random.rand(100)
y2 = np.random.rand(100)

plt.ion()
plt.show()

\\
    # Update live graph
    y1 = np.append(y1, temp)
    y2 = np.append(y2, hum)

    ax1.clear()
    ax1.plot(x, y1)
    ax1.set_title('Temperature')
    ax1.set_ylim(0, 100)

    ax2.clear()
    ax2.plot(x, y2)
    ax2.set_title('Humidity')
    ax2.set_ylim(0, 100)

    plt.draw()
    plt.pause(0.01)
```

I've change the whole python version to create this comunication throught a humidity and temperature Arduino sensor and this live graph.
I didn't try to use ipython (i don't know if is recommended).
Im new in this site so sorry for any misunderstandings.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: what is the problem correlated throught matplotlib.pyplot  and .clear() ; .plot() , set_title () , .setylim().

Comment: it cant analize the functions

Comment: the indentation is incorrect, so this code will not work.

Comment: there are also undefined variables.  what are `temp` and `hum` ?

Comment: so... what im gonna change?

Comment: nono i didn't put the whole code

Comment: if u want i write the code here?

Answer (score 0):

I don't use mathpotlib, but I've made a pygame graph class, which can be easily modified and used.

```
class Graph:
    def __init__(self,screen_width,screen_height,the_list,top,bottom,color):
        self.screen_width = screen_width
        self.screen_height = screen_height
        self.color = color
        self.zero = []
        for i in range(len(the_list)):
            self.zero.append(0)
        self.unit = (self.screen_width / (len(the_list)-1))
        self.edit(top,bottom,self.zero)
        self.draw()
        self.edit(top,bottom,the_list)
        self.draw()
    def map(self,temperature, start, finish ,height):
        y = height  - (height/(finish-start))*(temperature-start)
        return round(y)
    def edit(self,top,bottom,the_list):
        self.list = the_list
        x = 0
        for num in self.list:
            num = self.map(num,top,bottom,self.screen_height)
            self.list[x] = num
            x += 1
        x = 0
        for num in self.list:
            try:
                self.list[x] = (self.list[x],self.list[x+1])
            except:
                self.list[x] = (self.list[x],self.list[x])
            x += 1
    def draw(self):
        x = 0
        for num in self.list:
            pygame.draw.line(screen,self.color,(x*self.unit,self.list[x][0]),(x*self.unit+self.unit,self.list[x][1]),1)
            pygame.display.update()
            x += 1
```

And a demonstration:

```
import pygame,sys,math,random
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1920,1080))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
the_list = []
for n in range(100):
    the_list.append(n)
Graph(1920,1080,the_list,the_list[0],the_list[len(the_list)-1],0xFF0000)
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():    
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
```

Comment: oh ok thank you, anyway if i didn't resolve with matplotlib, i will use this method!!!